# WiX Toolset/HeatWave - Add dll to Installer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-installer, wix4

I'm trying to create a msi-Installer with the WiX Toolset v4 for a HelloWorld WPF-Application.
My problem is a missing dll which is not rolled out with the msi installation.

I've just created a WiX MSI Package via the Visual Studio 2022 'MSI Package (WiX v4)'-template and done two steps:

1. Add a Project Dependency to my HelloWorld WPF Application
2. Edit the ExampleComponents.wxs and change the Source Attribute from the File-Element to the WPF Applications Name

The wxs-files at this point:

ExampleComponents.wxs

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
        <File Source="WpfApp.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Folders.wxs

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer) !(bind.Property.ProductName)" />
    </StandardDirectory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Package.wxs

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Package Name="WpfAppPackage" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="32058e2f-46ed-4823-9795-d68433888c7f">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

The build results in a msi, wixpdb and a cab1.cab file.
To run the msi file leads to a new folder under C:/Program Files (x86)/... with the WpfApp.exe but I'm expecting the necessary WpfApp.dll as well which is missing at this point.

Trying to start the WpfApp.exe leads to nothing but an Eventlog-Entry which confirms my assumption.

So how do I configure my project for adding the dll in the installation process?

Comment: I assume you need to reference wpfHelloWorld to the wix4 project. Then inside wixproj file you need to use Heat task for generate some wxs file which then you need to include in Package.wxs file. (https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/heat)

Comment: @Modgudr: What is `WpfApp.dll`? `WpfApp.exe` is the WPF application. Where does the other assembly come from?

Comment: @mm8 the dll is generated during the building process and is part of the Wpf.App.exe. It does not come from any other project/library.The Application is just a simple HelloWorld Project which does nothing special and has no dependencies to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to update your components that you're telling it to install. The easiest way is to manually add the files you're looking to add to the `ComponentGroup`

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
        <File Source="WpfApp.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component>
        <File Source="WpfApp.dll"/>     <!-- Add this line with the path to your other file -->
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Don't put the .dll and the .exe in the same Component. Keep your Components small and only group things that *really* must travel together.

Comment: @RobMensching, I agree with that and edited the post to reflect different component groups for the sake of this example.

Comment: @RobMensching, but the exe and dll must travel together, so why separate them? And is there no other way to install the dependent dlls. It seems like a lot of work for larger solutions to reference every single dll.

Comment: @Modgudr, as was mentioned previously, using the "Heat" tool with WIX should be able to do this, but it takes a bit of configuring to set it up.